# In my story, a girl discovers who murdered her best friend and descends into madness. What is the genre?

Tags: novel, genre

The story I'm working on is about a girl whose best friend was murdered and how she is dealing with the aftermath. The main character is trying to figure out what happened, but it's not a murder mystery.

She discovers early in the story that is was her father who murdered her best friend. She doesn't know how to deal with that and slowly descends into madness, becoming terrified of her dad. He threatens her, and a bunch of other abusive stuff happens.

All of it ends with her killing her dad.

I have no idea what genre this is. It seems to me that it could be a mix of different genres, but I have no idea what just one could be.

Comment: To some extent, genres are made up, with arbitrary (and shifting) boundaries. Unless you're interested in changing the story to deliberately fit into a particular genre category, the genre shelf the bookshop puts it on is whatever your agent/publisher thinks would sell the most copies.

Answer (score 6):

Since the facts of the events are revealed early and the tension rises from her coming to terms with the events and what will she do, I think this could be considered a psychological thriller. The thriller part comes from what she will do and the psychological part comes from that so much of the story revolves around the main character's mindset and thoughts and reactions to the murder and the murderer.

Comment: Psychological thriller is what I think, too. But if the story is less driven by increasing menace and more quietly realistic, it might simply be general fiction.

Answer (score 0):

I think it definitely belongs in the psychological genre. From the description, I'm not getting the impression it counts as a thriller. As I understand it, a thriller is fast-paced and requires a lot of action and twists; if it's more focussed on the inner processes in the protagonist's mind and less on new outer action, then I wouldn't say it's a thriller. I'd classify it as [psychological fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychological_fiction) and leave it at that.